# EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Completion block

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks

**ANSWER**

I heve a mistake when i call the fetchDailyForecast it should looks like

```
  [self.fetchController fetchDailyForecast:self.currentLocation.coordinate completionBlock:^(DailyModel *newModel) {
        _dailyCondition = newModel;
        NSLog(@"newModel = %@", _dailyCondition);
    }];
```

**END**

I try to use bloc's and wait but have a bad_access exaction. Firstly i call method from MangeDataController.m

> [self.fetchController
>   fetchDailyForecast:self.currentLocation.coordinate
>   completionBlock:(void(^)(DailyModel *))_dailyCondition];

where the dailyCondition is instance of DailyModel. 
Secondly here is **fetchDailyForecast** method realization in FetchController.m.

```
-(void)fetchDailyForecast:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate completionBlock:(void(^)(DailyModel *))completionBlock {
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat=%f&lon=%f&units=imperial&cnt=7%@", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude, _key];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
    [self fetchJSONfromURL:urlString completionBlock:^(NSDictionary *weatherData) {
        completionBlock([[DailyModel alloc] dataFromDictionaryDaily:weatherData]); --- (here the bad access);
    }];
}
```

and thirdly in **fatchDailyForecast** i call **fetchJSONfromURL** here is realization:

```
-(void)fetchJSONfromURL:(NSString *)urlString completionBlock:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))completionBlock {
    NSLog(@"url = %@", urlString);
    [_manager GET:urlString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responceObject) {
        if (responceObject) {
            completionBlock(responceObject);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"responce object error");
        }
    }
          failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error){

              NSLog(@"error %@", error);
          }];
}
```

P.S. I think my mistake is that i try to pass day **_dailyCondition** but should pass something different. Thanks for any help!

**EDIT ------- DailyModel.m **

```
#import "DailyModel.h"

@implementation DailyModel


-(id)dataFromDictionaryDaily:(NSDictionary *)dic {
     NSArray *arrayWithDictionarys = [dic objectForKey:@"list"];
    NSDictionary *dictionaryWithWeekDays = [self indexKeyedDictionaryFromArray:arrayWithDictionarys];
   // NSLog(@"dictionary with dayweeks = %@", dictionaryWithWeekDays);
    _arrayWithTemp = [NSMutableArray new];
    _arrayWithDate = [NSMutableArray new];
    _arrayWithIcon = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        NSNumber* key = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
        [self addValuesToArrayWithTemp:dictionaryWithWeekDays key:key index:i];
        [self addValuesToArrayWithDate:dictionaryWithWeekDays key:key index:i];
        [self addValueToArrayWithImage:dictionaryWithWeekDays key:key index:i];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSDictionary *) indexKeyedDictionaryFromArray:(NSArray *)array
{
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:
     ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
         NSNumber *index = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:idx];
         [mutableDictionary setObject:obj forKey:index];
     }];
    NSDictionary *result = [NSDictionary.alloc initWithDictionary:mutableDictionary];
    return result;
}

-(void) addValuesToArrayWithTemp:(NSDictionary *)inputDic key:(NSNumber *)key index:(int)ind {
    NSDictionary *currentDic = [inputDic objectForKey:key];
    NSDictionary *temp = [currentDic objectForKey:@"temp"];
    _tempLow = [temp objectForKey:@"min"];
    _tempHigh = [temp objectForKey:@"max"];
    _tempLow = [self convertToCelsius:_tempLow];
    _tempHigh = [self convertToCelsius:_tempHigh];
    NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f / %.02f", _tempLow.floatValue , _tempHigh.floatValue];
    [_arrayWithTemp insertObject:tempString atIndex:ind];
}

-(NSNumber *)convertToCelsius:(NSNumber *)far {
    double f =  (far.doubleValue - 32) / 1.8;
    NSNumber *celsius = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:f];

    return celsius;
}

-(void) addValuesToArrayWithDate:(NSDictionary *)inputDic key:(NSNumber *)key index:(int)ind {
    NSDictionary *currenDic = [inputDic objectForKey:key];
    NSNumber *tempNumber = [currenDic objectForKey:@"dt"];
    double unixTimeStamp = tempNumber.doubleValue;
    NSString* weekDay = [self convertToWeekDay:unixTimeStamp];
    [_arrayWithDate insertObject:weekDay atIndex:ind];
}

-(NSString *)convertToWeekDay:(double) unixtime {

    NSTimeInterval _interval = unixtime;
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    return dateString;
}

-(void) addValueToArrayWithImage:(NSDictionary *)inputDic key:(NSNumber *)key index:(int)ind {
    NSDictionary *currenDic = [inputDic objectForKey:key];
    NSArray *weatherArray = [currenDic objectForKey:@"weather"];
    NSDictionary *weather = weatherArray[0];

    _icon = [weather objectForKey:@"icon"];
    _icon = [self currentImageString:_icon];

    [_arrayWithIcon insertObject:_icon atIndex:ind];
}

-(NSString *)currentImageString:(NSString *)ico {
    NSDictionary *dic = @{
                          @"01d" : @"weather-clear",
                          @"02d" : @"weather-few",
                          @"03d" : @"weather-few",
                          @"04d" : @"weather-broken",
                          @"09d" : @"weather-shower",
                          @"10d" : @"weather-rain",
                          @"11d" : @"weather-tstorm",
                          @"13d" : @"weather-snow",
                          @"50d" : @"weather-mist",
                          @"01n" : @"weather-moon",
                          @"02n" : @"weather-few-night",
                          @"03n" : @"weather-few-night",
                          @"04n" : @"weather-broken",
                          @"09n" : @"weather-shower",
                          @"10n" : @"weather-rain-night",
                          @"11n" : @"weather-tstorm",
                          @"13n" : @"weather-snow",
                          @"50n" : @"weather-mist",
                          };
    ico = [dic objectForKey:ico];
    return ico;
}
@end
```

**EDIT 2**

I add the condition into **(void)fetchDailyForecast:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate completionBlock:(void(^)(DailyModel *))completionBlock**  and now app don't crash but it's still not work and nslog say @"nothing"

> [self fetchJSONfromURL:urlString completionBlock:^(NSDictionary
>   *weatherData) {  if (completionBlock) {  completionBlock(model = [[DailyModel alloc] dataFromDictionaryDaily:weatherData]);  } else { 
>   NSLog(@"nothing");  }  }];

Comment: What is 'DailyModel`?

Comment: @Mr.UB Daily modal is controller which fetch data from NSDictionary. I edit my post check updates.

Comment: What is the output of `print (weatherData)`?

Comment: @Mr.UB JSON dictionary, with correct values

Comment: @Mr.UB it's just a sample " city =     {
        coord =         {
            lat = "37.323002";
            lon = "-122.032181";
        };
        country = US;
        id = 5341145;
        name = Cupertino;
        population = 0;"

Comment: Try adding break-point inside `for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {` loop and check when does the error happen.

Comment: error was after 0 loop end here is the text "2016-10-03 15:06:58.060 weatherapp[12193:426362] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124774/discussion-between-dmitriy-babinskiy-and-mr-ub).

Comment: As the error suggests, you are adding nil element to the array. Does the program goes inside `addValuesToArrayWithTemp` method?

Comment: @Mr.UB i think it because dictionaryWithWeekDays is nil

Comment: but i pass the dictionary here completionBlock([[DailyModel alloc] dataFromDictionaryDaily:weatherData]);

Comment: @Mr.UB i try to repeat this error with nil but everything ok all loop working and it show error after return self in FetchController and error is "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address = 0x10)"

Comment: @Mr.UB after [[DailyModel alloc] dataFromDictionaryDaily:weatherData] the completionBlock is nil i miss understand why